# Hide sub directories in while loop

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make a script that creates soft/symbolic links, but should also detect if links already exist in the '~/linkedfiles' directory, but the problem is that $file also contains sub directories. ($file will look like this: '~/realfiles/files/file23.gz', but I need 'file23.gz' only.) So my question is, how do I remove the sub directories in $file?

Here is some code as an example:

```
for file in ~/realfiles/files/*.gz
do

echo "Linking file: $file"
ln -s $file ~/linkedfiles
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "[FAIL] Linking of $file failed!"
else
echo "[SUCCESS] $file successfully linked."
fi
done
```

Comment: `man find`, search for `-type`.

Comment: As per your code, `$file` will contain `.gz` files. How it contains sub directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want the base name of the path.  There are two ways to do that — the classic reliable way is with the [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) command, and the modern not-always-reliable way is with a [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
for file in ~/realfiles/files/*.gz
do
    echo "Linking file: $file"
    ln -s "$file" "~/linkedfiles/$(basename "$file")"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then echo "[FAIL] Linking of $file failed!"
    else echo "[SUCCESS] $file successfully linked."
    fi
done
```

Or:

```
for file in ~/realfiles/files/*.gz
do
    echo "Linking file: $file"
    ln -s "$file" "~/linkedfiles/${file##*/}"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then echo "[FAIL] Linking of $file failed!"
    else echo "[SUCCESS] $file successfully linked."
    fi
done
```

In both scripts, the file `~/realfiles/files/file23.gz` will be linked to `~/linkedfiles/file23.gz`, which is what I think you are after (though there is room to improve the clarity of the question, such as by citing the desired result for the sample file name).

Answer (score 0):

**Slight modification of original script would do**

```
for filename in ~/realfiles/files/*.gz
do
echo "Linking file: $file"
[[ -h "~/linkedfiles/${var##*/}" ]] && continue
ln -s "$filename" ~/linkedfiles/
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "[FAIL] Linking of $filename failed!"
else
  echo "[SUCCESS] $filename successfully linked."
fi
done
```

**Notes**

- The `-h` option with `if` [[ checks ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) if the file is a symbolic link
- `${var##*/}` gives you the base name. Check [[ parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: `find` doesn't really add anything past what `-h` already does (although you could add `! -type l` to the `find` command and drop the `-h` test in the loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
targetdir="$HOME/linkedfiles"    
for filename in $HOME/realfiles/files/*.gz; do
    # if filename is a regular file then ...
    if [[ -f "${filename}" ]]; then
        # if softlink does not exist in target then link it
        if [[ ! -h "${targetdir}/${filename##*/}" ]]; then
            echo "Linking ${filename}"
            ln -s "${filename}" "${targetdir}"
            (( $? == 0 )) && echo 'Link created' || echo 'Create link fails'
        else
            echo "Skipping because ${filename##*/} exists in ${targetdir}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: I prefer to use: ln -sf ${filename} targetdir

Comment: `cmd; (( $? == 0 )) && echo` is more succinctly, idiomatically, and portably written `cmd && echo`.